# Pandas: sum column values against specific value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I am using this data frame:

```
InvoiceNo    Amount    Year-Month
1            100       2019-01
2            125       2019-02
3            200       2019-02
4            300       2019-03
5            120       2019-03
6            350       2019-03
7            500       2019-04
8            230       2019-04
9            100       2019-04
10           200       2019-05
```

I want to sum up value against all the same months and display new column with those monthly values like this:

```
InvoiceNo    Amount    Year-Month    MonthlyValue
1            100       2019-01       100
2            125       2019-02       325
3            200       2019-02       325
4            300       2019-03       770
5            120       2019-03       770
6            350       2019-03       770
7            500       2019-04       830
8            230       2019-04       830
9            100       2019-04       830
10           200       2019-05       200
```

I tried `df['MonthlyValue'] = df.groupby(['Year-Month'])['Year-Month'].transform(sum)` and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need specify column `Amount` after `groupby`:

```
df['MonthlyValue'] = df.groupby('Year-Month')['Amount'].transform('sum')
```